# Does the time to call document ready differ based on Internet speeds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, networking

Suppose I have the following javascript

```
$('body').css("opacity","0");

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css("opacity","1");
});
```

Notice that I set the opacity of body to 0 outside of any ready or load block and that I then set it back to 1 once the document is ready.

My question: Suppose I'm on a real slow internet connection on a very heavy weight page, will the time that the body is invisible be longer than if I was on a really fast internet connection on the same page?  Can you please explain why?

I'm developing soley for mobile if that matters.

Comment: It could take longer to load the resources needed to render the page and the time it takes before the DOM is ready on a slow connection, but why would it matter. Why it's like this should be pretty darn obvious if you've ever downloaded anything from the web.

Comment: You could set the opacity to 0 using `style` rather than jQuery.

Comment: @adeneo Disregarding the above code, while the resourcing are loading and the DOM is being prepared, is anything being rendered/displayed on the screen?

Comment: You can easily answer all these questions yourself.

Comment: @ikegami Why would that matter? I have to already have jQuery loaded on the page so that I can use $(document).ready correct?

Comment: @ikegami Sorry, how can I test if anything is rendered on the screen before $(document).ready?  Sorry, I have a limited knowledge of the HTML rendering process

Comment: By the time the document is ready, all the elements in the DOM are rendered, if they are rendered correctly and styled etc. is another question.

Comment: @Nosrettap If your code's early execution is critical, you might consider putting it in a `script` tag that follows the targetted elements rather than waiting until the document is ready. However, while `window.onload` should wait for images and other resources, `document.ready` shouldn't, unless `DOMContentLoaded` is not supported (that's as far as I know).

Comment: @adeneo Ok, so in that case is the following true: Adding the above code will cause users to see a blank screen for longer than if that javascript had not been added.  Additionally, this increase will be greater for those on slower connections.      Thanks for your help.

Comment: That depends on where you place the script tag I suppose.

Comment: @adeneo This will be the first script tag very close to the top of the file.  Why would that matter?

Comment: javascript is loaded when the browser encounters it, so if placing the script tag at the bottom, right before `</body>` the other DOM elements would be available and rendered at the time the script runs. If you place the script at the top the script will load before the rest of the DOM is ready etc.